# Dynamic menu privilege not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Here is my Code

```
<ul class="nav side-menu">


              <?php 
            $mnquery=$ob->showDataall("select * from menus where parent_id='0' and delet='0'");
            foreach($mnquery as $value)
                {
                    $selquery=$ob->showDataall("select * from menu_permission where staff_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
                    foreach($selquery as $nquery)
                        {
                            foreach(explode(",",$nquery['permission']) as $mnu)
                                {
                                    if($value['menu_id']==$mnu)
                                        {
                                    ?>
        <li><a <?php if($value['menu_hyper']!='#'){ echo 'href="'.$value['menu_hyper'].'"';}?>><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><?php echo $value['menu_name']; if($value['menu_hyper']=='#'){?><span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span><?php }?></a>
                                    <?php
                                        $submnquery=$ob->showDataall("select * from menus where parent_id='".$mnu."' and delet='0'");
                                        if(!empty($submnquery))
                                        foreach($submnquery as $subvalue)
                                            {
                                                if($subvalue['parent_id']==$mnu)
                                                    {
                                    ?>
                                                    <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                                        <li><a <?php if($subvalue['menu_hyper']!='#'){ echo 'href="'.$subvalue['menu_hyper'].'"';}?>><?php echo $subvalue['menu_name']; if($subvalue['menu_hyper']=='#'){?><span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span><?php }?></a>
                                                        <?php
                                                            $chldmnquery=$ob->showDataall("select * from menus where parent_id='".$subvalue['menu_id']."' and delet='0'");
                                                            if(!empty($chldmnquery))
                                                            foreach($chldmnquery as $chldvalue)
                                                                {
                                                                    if($chldvalue['parent_id']==$subvalue['menu_id'])
                                                                    {
                                                        ?>
                                                            <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                                                <li><a href="<?php echo $chldvalue['menu_hyper'];?>"><?php echo $chldvalue['menu_name'];?></a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        <?php
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                        ?>

                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                <?php
                                                    }
                                            }
                                ?>
                                    </li>
                                <?php
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
              ?>
</ul>
```

Here is my function showDataall

```
public function showDataall($result) 
    {
        $q = $this->conn->prepare($result) or die("failed!");
        $q->execute();
        while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            $data[] = $r;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Here is my Table named '**menus**'

```
     menu_id       menu_name            menu_hyper                 parent_id    delet
        1         Master Settings            #                         0         0
        2         Add New Menu       ../pages/menu_add.php             1         0
        3         Menu Permission    ../pages/menu_permissions.php     1         0
        4         Role               ../pages/add_role.php             1         0
        5         Staff              ../pages/add_staff.php            1         0
        6         Add Product        ../pages/product_add.php          0         0
```

Here is my Other table named '**menu_permission**'

```
  id    staff_id    permission
   1       1        1,2,3,4,5,6
   2       2        1,4
```

I allow all menu privilege for '**staff_id=1**'
I allow menu_id **1** and **4** for '**staff_id=2**'
**staff_id=1** is logged in all menus shown but **staff_id=2** is logged in all menus are shown 
 I allow only two menus for staff_id=2 (menu_id = 1 and menu_id = 2) how to solve this problem

Please help me....

Comment: Man, you got 5 loops one in an other... you should use PHP functions to look for a value. replace `foreach(explode(",",$nquery['permission']) as $mnu)` with `if(in_array($subvalue['parent_id'],$nquery['permission'])` for instance, to check if a value is in an array... Doing things like this will make your code much more readable... So much more debugable... Then you should log what goes in each if/foreach, to check where is the problem...

Comment: I try this Its not work

Comment: Here you have to do a full dubug. Try to make the first loop work by checking what data you get when you are into the loop. Once you did that, check if the 2nd loop is good etc... What I suggested does not solve the problem, it just helps making your code clear and easier to debug... This is so huge we can't help you quickly...

Comment: first loop working good but the second loop is the problem

Comment: So `$selquery` may not be filled as you expected ? can you do a var_dump or print_r on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this part:

```
foreach(explode(",",$nquery['permission']) as $mnu)
```

to:

```
$mypermission = explode(",",$nquery['permission']);
```

and then

```
foreach($mypermission as $mnu)
```

Comment: sorry same problem

Answer (score 0):

**I write on my Knowledge ... Its Work Perfectly
 any one help me to simplify this code**

```
              <?php 
            $mnquery=$ob->showDataall("select * from menus where parent_id='0' and delet='0'");
            foreach($mnquery as $value)
                {
                    $selquery=$ob->showDataall("select * from menu_permission where staff_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
                    foreach($selquery as $nquery)
                        {
                            foreach(explode(",",$nquery['permission']) as $mnu)
                                {
                                    if($value['menu_id']==$mnu)
                                        {
                                    ?>
        <li><a <?php if($value['menu_hyper']!='#'){ echo 'href="'.$value['menu_hyper'].'"';}?>><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><?php echo $value['menu_name']; if($value['menu_hyper']=='#'){?><span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span><?php }?></a>
                                    <?php
                                        $submnquery=$ob->showDataall("select * from menus where parent_id='".$mnu."' and parent_id!='0' and delet='0'");
                                        if(!empty($submnquery))
                                        foreach($submnquery as $subvalue)
                                            {
                                                $selquery=$ob->showDataall("select * from menu_permission where staff_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
                                                foreach($selquery as $nquery)
                                                    {
                                                        foreach(explode(",",$nquery['permission']) as $mnua)
                                                            {
                                                if($subvalue['menu_id']==$mnua)
                                                    {
                                    ?>
                                                    <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                                        <li><a <?php if($subvalue['menu_hyper']!='#'){ echo 'href="'.$subvalue['menu_hyper'].'"';}?>><?php echo $subvalue['menu_name']; if($subvalue['menu_hyper']=='#'){?><span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span><?php }?></a>





                                                  <?php
                                                            $chldmnquery=$ob->showDataall("select * from menus where parent_id='".$subvalue['menu_id']."' and delet='0'");
                                                            if(!empty($chldmnquery))
                                                            foreach($chldmnquery as $chldvalue)
                                                                {
                                                                    $selquery=$ob->showDataall("select * from menu_permission where staff_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
                                                foreach($selquery as $nquery)
                                                    {
                                                        foreach(explode(",",$nquery['permission']) as $mnub)
                                                            {
                                                                    if($chldvalue['menu_id']==$mnub)
                                                                    {
                                                        ?>
                                                            <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                                                <li><a href="<?php echo $chldvalue['menu_hyper'];?>"><?php echo $chldvalue['menu_name'];?></a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        <?php
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                        ?>      

                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                <?php
                                                    }
                                            }
                        }
                                            }
                                ?>
                                    </li>
                                <?php
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
              ?>
</ul>
```